# Touchpad quit working between kernel 5.8.0-38 and 5.8.0-45

Tags: kernel, touchpad

I have a Dell Precision 7300 and the touchpad worked fine with kernel 5.8.0-38, but the update to 5.8.0-45 caused the touchpad to quit working. The same touchpad problem also exists in 5.8.0-44.

When in 5.8.0-45, I can insert a USB mouse and it works fine.

I've been digging around in logs to try to figure out what's going on, but as far as I can tell no device is found.

Have you seen a problem like this?  Have you suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).  If you have encountered a bug, you should file a bug report.

Comment: Over the years, I've not had the feeling that reporting bugs does much good.  Figuring out what's wrong and applying a workaround more likely to succeed.

Comment: *"applying a workaround"* - You can use the older kernel as a workaround since you already know it works. Bug reporting is **essential**!  If nobody reported bugs, many would never get fixed, especially if it only applies in a few circumstances. For example, it could be the case that this bug only affects your exact model touchpad. Even if someone else has already reported this particular bug, adding your report still helps the people who actually "figure out what's wrong" and write patches to fix them.